# Finding the basis of for a polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question about finding a basis for this polynomial space.

> Let $V=\{p \in P_3 |P(1)=P(-1)\}.$

> a) If $p=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 \in P_3$, find a condition on the coefficients of $p$ for $p$ to be in $V$.

> b) Find a basis for $V$, and write down dim(V).

I already did part a)

a) $p(a)=a_3+a_2+a_1+a_0=-a_3+a_2-a_1+a_0$ which directly implies that $a_3=-a_1$ so we're done.

b) Since $a_3=-a_1$, this implies that any general $p(x)=-a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$.

If I rearrange this, I get $p(x)=(x-x^3)a_1+x^2a_2+xa_1+a_0$ so would my basis just be $\{1,x^2,x-x^3\}$? This implies that the dimension is 3 which is not consistent with what should happen in $P_3$. Is this method correct?

In general, I'm a little confused about how to generally find the basis for a vector space subject to a condition of some kind. I realize there are multiple possible bases but it's really hard knowing where to kind of start.

Also for part b), If my answer is correct, don't I have to prove that the vectors are linearly independent and span $P_3$ as well?

**EDIT:** I removed $x$ from my basis. I accidently put $\{1,x,x^2,x-x^3\}$ at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\dim P_3 = 4$ and $\varphi(p) = p(-1)-p(1)$ is a non zero linear form. As $V = (\ker \varphi )\cap P_3$, you have $\dim V=3$.

$x$ is not an element of $V$ as you said. $\{x^2,x-x^3,1\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: Isn't this bad though? The dimension should be $4$ right? I have $P_3$. Don't I need $4$ basis vectors?

Comment: No the dimension of $P_3$ is equal to $4$. The dimension of $V$ is equal to $3$. If $\dim V=4$ you would have $V=P_3$ which is not the case.

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I don't understand this correctly but is $V$ not just the space of all polynomials of degree $3$? So thus, would the dimension of $V$ not be $4$?

Comment: If $V$ would be equal to $P_3$, any polynomial $p$ of degree at most equal to $3$ would be such that $p(1)=p(-1)$. Is that the case of $p(x) = x$?

Comment: Well no, since $1 \neq -1$, but what this this have to do with dimension? To my understanding, Dimension is the number of basis vectors for a vector space. Is that not $3$ here this case and I need $4$ linearly independent vectors to describe polynomials in $P_4$?

Is it because my basis vectors already have the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ so I don't need any more vectors to describe the space since I can do it with just $3$ vectors?

Comment: Yes you only need $3$ polynomials to span an element of $V$. This is why the dimension of $V$ is equal to $3$.

Comment: Ahh okay I see! So it is incorrect to think that the dimension has to equal the same as the polynomial space. As long as the basis describes the space given, then the dimension of the basis vectors does not have to be the same as the overall space (In this case, $P_3$).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As you proved $$p(x)\in V\iff p(x)=-a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=a_2x^2+(x-x^3)a_1+a_0.$$
Therefore, $$V=\text{Span}\{x^2, x-x^3,1\}.$$

Prove that $\{x^2,x-x^3,1\}$ is free, and conclude.

Comment: Hi. I think for $a_1$ it should be $(x-x^3)$, not $(1-x^3)$.

Comment: @FutureMathperson: you right.